# How to build a setInterval-like task?

Tags: julia, task

This is my idea

```
task=@task begin
while true
    sleep(1)
    foo()
    if should_end
        # ?
    end
end
end
```

But there are some problems

1. are there any simple ways to contact other than using `global should_end`?
2. how to end the task from inside the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While implementing something like this can be a good exercise, note that [Timers are in the standard library](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.Timer-Tuple%7BFunction,%20Real%7D) and they are similar to the JS functions you may be used to because Julia and Node.js both use libuv internally. Whether you use Node.js `setInterval` or `Timeout`, or Julia `Timer` eventually [`uv_timer_start`](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/timer.html) is called (although the creation and low-level management of timers is different in the respective runtimes).

To answer your **2nd** question, you can just [`break`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/#man-loops) in the `if` expression:

```
julia> should_end = false
false

julia> task = @task begin
           while true
               sleep(1)
               if should_end
                   break
               end
           end
           "Tasks can return a value"
       end
Task (runnable) @0x00007fca1c9c3990

julia> schedule(task)
Task (runnable) @0x00007fca1c9c3990

julia> task
Task (runnable) @0x00007fca1c9c3990

julia> should_end = true;sleep(1)

julia> task
Task (done) @0x00007fca1c9c3990

julia> fetch(task)
"Tasks can return a value"
```

As for the **1st** question, there is a lot of information in the Julia docs, e.g. the [Asynchronous Programming](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/asynchronous-programming) section. As is described there, [Channels](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/asynchronous-programming/#Communicating-with-Channels) can be used for communication between tasks (when suitable). Note that `should_end` doesn't have to be `global`. A task wraps a function and that function can capture variables in enclosing scopes (`@task begin a = 1 end` is really just `Task(() -> begin a = 1 end)`.

Here is a short example using a `Timer` and a `Channel` to send data to a task:

```
function pinger(n)
    ping() = parse(Float64, match(r"time=(.*) ms", read(`ping -c 1 8.8.8.8`, String))[1])
    ch = Channel{Float64}(0)

    pinger = Timer(0.0; interval=1.0) do timer
        put!(ch, ping())
    end

    summer = @task begin
        total = 0.0
        count = 0
        while count < n
            total += take!(ch)
            count += 1
        end
        total / count
    end
    schedule(summer)
    fetch(summer)
end
```

```
julia> pinger(3)
19.5
```